# If $|G|=7 \times 11 \times 19$, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

If $|G|=7 \times 11 \times 19$,

then $G$ is abelian.

I have tried it by Sylow theorem but I failed.

Could someone give me the details?

Comment: Let's go with the Sylow 7 subgroup $P_7$. There are $p_7\equiv 1\mod 7$ such subgroups and $p_7|11\times 19$. Since neither $11$ nor $19$ are $1\mod 7$, $p_7=1$ and it is normal. Same for $P_{11}, P_{19}$. Moreover the only elements these three groups have in common is the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that $$G\cong \mathbb Z/7\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/11\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z.$$

Notice that Sylow (or in fact Cauchy) tells you that there is an element of order $7$, an element of order $11$ and an other of order $19$.

It's almost finish.